# On the canonical morphism $B\otimes_A N \to N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let  $A$  and $B$ be two commutative rings with unit.    Let $\rho: A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism and $N$ a $B$-module (and thereby a $A$-module).

**Question:** Is there a canonical morphism $B\otimes_A N \to N$? If so, what is the expression of this morphism?

Comment: $N$ is a $B$-module. So there is a scalar multiplication map, and it’s bilinear…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the $A$-bilinear map:
$$\begin{align*} B\times N\to N \\ b\times n \to bn. \end{align*}$$
By the universal property, this induces a unique $A$-module (surjective) homomorphism  $$B\otimes_{A} N\to N.$$

Comment: Your inverse map is not correct unless the tensor product is with respect to $R$, which is not the case in the question (also as a general rule try not to change the notations used in the question).

Comment: I didn't pay attention that the tensor product being over $A$, I will edit my answer.